# How to Convert JS and GSAP button into REACT JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gsap

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="toggle">
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <span class="one"></span>
            <span class="two"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: a;
}

.toggle {
    position: relative;
}

.menu-btn {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40px;
    height: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.two {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var t1 = new TimelineMax({paused: true});
    
    t1.to('.one', 0.8, {
        y: 6,
        rotation: 45,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut
    });
    
    t1.to('.two', 0.8, {
        y: -6,
        rotation: -45,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        delay: -0.8
    });
    
    t1.reverse();
    $(document).on('click', '.menu-btn', function() {
        t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
    });
});
```

***CAN ANYONE TELL ME HOW TO DO THE SAME THING IN REACT.***

**PLEASE INCLUDE GSAP :**
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"</script>`

***YOU CAN FIND THE WORKING EXAMPLE HERE :***
https://codepen.io/doesnotexist/pen/XWXKMmJ

I just messed up things at first I thought, I'll just copy paste the exact code in REACT and it'll work fine but after saving the code the react gave me hundreds of error.

Comment: You don't copy and paste everything into React; you learn what each part does and use the equivalent React functions. `$(document).ready()` for instance is React's `componentDidMount`. Also, GSAP has a react library, and it comes with docs and examples: https://bitworking.github.io/react-gsap/src-components-timeline

Comment: @ChrisG While that library can be helpful, it's not created or maintained by GreenSock. You actually don't need to use the library to use GSAP with React.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sure, I was just pointing out options to the OP. Mostly trying to nudge them into gaining experience and googling more.

Comment: @ChrisG now it is maintained by GREENSOCK.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that you probably don't need GSAP to do this. So if that's a requirement, this may not suit your need. I used simple CSS animations to rotate the two bars. See below.

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-toggle-6vefo?file=/src/App.js

**React Code**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function MenuButton(props) {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      class={`menu-btn ${toggle ? "on" : "off"}`}
      onMouseOver={() => setToggle(true)}
      onMouseOut={() => setToggle(false)}
    >
      <span class="one"></span>
      <span class="two"></span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Add the button to your React component like

```
<MenuButton />
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.menu-btn.off span:first-child {
  transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(0deg);
}
.menu-btn.off span:last-child {
  transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-btn.on span:first-child {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-btn.on span:last-child {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```